# selecting multiple values in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have been having alot of trouble to get multiple values in a numpy array. For example if a have a array

```
array = np.array([[1, 2, 3 , 12 , 14],
                 [2, 67, 94, 1, 54],
                 [12, 9, 0, 10, 3],
                 [2, 45, 2, 21, 85]])
```

Imagine i need to get this array back

```
([[3, 12],
  [94, 1],
  [0, 10],
  [2, 21]])
```

Or any other array i would like u to teach me how to get them but not just this one in specific i would like a general explanation or at least a link to a place where i can find one

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Answer (score 1):

```
x = array[:,2:4]
print(x)
```

The above code will do the trick. You can do the slicing(The : is the slicing operator) in each dimension separated by comma. Here the first colon (:) is for first dimension, i.e. you want to takes values from all the rows. The 2:4 for second dimension indicates that you want to take from column 2 to 4-1, i.e 3 inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your specific question is:

```
array[:, 2:4]

Out: 
array([[ 3, 12],
       [94,  1],
       [ 0, 10],
       [ 2, 21]])
```

What is happening is that the first index is referencing the rows that you want. The second index is the columns that you want. The character ":" means "all", and you want all the rows for some specific columns. The specific columns are referenced as 2:4; which means start at column 2 (remember Python indexing starts at 0), and you want to take all columns through, but not including, 4.

Comment: i sometimes see people using things like array[::, 2:4] or semething like that but i would like to know what does the '::' mean